# Webservice account doesn't have permissions to Select on a table or execute on a Function even though it is part of the Public Role

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design, permissions

My previous experience has been with AD and NTFS permissions, not SQL Server permissions.  I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue where our webservice account doesn't have the ability to Select in tables, nor execute a function within a database.

Main DB Permissions:

- public: database role (assume defaults)
- web service account/login:  connect

Web Service account/login:

- connect to DB
- has public role privileges

This is the same sort of setup we use for our other applications, (but on a different instance), and they are working fine.  I'm cross-referencing and trying to make sure everything is set just like for the DBs and Logins on the other instance.

The only way I can get SELECT to work on the tables is to explicitly grant the web service account "allow select" to the specific table.

We don't have to do this for our other apps...

What am I missing?  What should I be looking for?

Why doesn't the web service account/login have "SELECT" via the Public role?  (Our other instances work this way, why not this one?)

Comment: `public` has little to no permissions in a database (by default it won't be able to use `SELECT` against any objects, `EXEC` any SP's, `VIEW` any definitions, etc, etc). You would be better creating a user in the database for the login your web service is using, and giving that user the minimal permissions it needs on that database.

Comment: @Larnu after continued troubleshooting, I didn't ask the right question.  I think this is now a context issue.  Webservice login has connect to DB, and EXEC on the 'main' stored proc.  I'm trying to fire off dynamic SQL from within a SP.  How can I ensure that the SP is using EXEC under the context in which the SP was originally called?

Comment: Read the following article: http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html